# React axios post request to java spring with stripe api cors error

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors, stripe-payments

I am using spring backend code with stripe api to implement a payment portal with react front end. However when I used a post request I am getting following error,

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/payment-gateway/charge' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

These are my backend codes,
Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PaymentGatewayRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PaymentGatewayRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller class,

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/payment-gateway")
public class PaymentGatewayController {
    @Autowired
    private final PaymentGatewayService paymentGatewayService;

    @PostMapping("/charge")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<String> charge(@RequestBody PaymentRequest paymentRequest) throws StripeException{
        String chargeId = paymentGatewayService.charge(paymentRequest);
        return chargeId != null ? new ResponseEntity<String>(chargeId, HttpStatus.OK) :
                new ResponseEntity<>("Please check the credit card details",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Service class,

```
@Service
public class PaymentGatewayService {

    @Value("$sk_test_*******")
    private String secretKey;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Stripe.apiKey=secretKey;
    }

    public String charge(PaymentRequest chargeRequest) throws StripeException {
        Map<String,Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<>();
        chargeParams.put("amount",chargeRequest.getAmount());
        chargeParams.put("currency", PaymentRequest.Currency.USD);
        chargeParams.put("source", chargeRequest.getToken().getId());

        Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
        return charge.getId();
    }
}
```

Note: PaymentRequest is a custom class to get the above information.

Frontend code,

```
import React from "react";
import Stripe from "react-stripe-checkout";
import axios from "axios";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
const Payments = ({ price }) => {
  const publishKey =
    "pk_test_*********";
  const stripePrice = 200;

  const onToken = (token) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/payment-gateway/charge", {
        amount: stripePrice,
        token,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        alert("payment success");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <StripeCheckout
      amount={stripePrice}
      label="Pay now"
      token={onToken}
      stripeKey={publishKey}
      currency="USD"
    />
  );
};
export default Payments;
```

I can't understand why I am getting the cors policy error as I added the `@CrossOrigin("*")` annotation in the controller class. Even I tried by adding the following code to my main class, but still I am getting that error.

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Axios silently adds a `Content-Type` header to the request when the second argument of `axios.post` is an object. Accordingly, a necessary condition for preflight to succeed is to explicitly allow that request header in your CORS configuration on the server side.

Comment: @jub0bs did you mean to add the `allowHeaders="Content-Type"` in the @CrossOrigin annotation?

Comment: @jub0bs I tried it earlier but didn't work.